# Preview conversion rate with Binance API

Tags: binance-api-client

I am working in a small Android App interacting with Binance API. I am trying to make something similar to:

```
https://www.binance.com/es/convert
```

That is, I would like to view the rate or price of a conversion and if I am interested in this rate, confirm it. With the end point:

```
/api/v3/order
```

I don't see the way of doing it, I just understand that you can place a market order and get the current price but I would like to preview the price proposed and confirm it in a few second in the same way that the above URL does it.
Could you please show me an example on how to do it or give me any clue?
Many thanks,
Joaquin

Answer (score 0):

`POST /api/v3/order` endpoint is used for placing an real order into your account.

If you wish to get the latest price from the market, this ticket price is more suitable: `GET /api/v3/ticker/price`